# How do I dynamically allocate memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to make a word counter program and want to dynamically allocate memory for the string without extra space. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strmalloc(char *string);
char *user_input = NULL;

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter a sentence to find out the number of words: ");
    strmalloc(user_input);
    printf("You entered %s", user_input);
    return 0;
}

char *strmalloc(char *string) {
    char *tmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, index = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (size <= index) {
            size += 1;
            tmp = realloc(string, size);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(string);
                string = NULL;
                break;
            }
            string = tmp;
        }
        string[index++] = ch;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Enter a sentence to find out the number of words: Testing program
You entered (null)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I thought that in the while loop, I reallocate 1 byte of memory until the string fits just right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function returns a value, but it is not used by the caller.

Comment: you mean I should assign the function to user_input?

Comment: @wildplasser it does not have to be used but double pointer is needed as in my answer

Comment: Yep. (or pass the pointer by pointer, which is needlessy complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functiuon:

`char *strmalloc(char *string) {` ===> `char *strmalloc(char **string) {`

`tmp = realloc(string, size);` ===> `tmp = realloc(*string, size);`

`string = NULL;` ===> `*string = NULL;`

`string = tmp;` ===> `*string = tmp`;

`string[index++] = ch;` ===> `(*string)[index++] = ch;`

`return string;` ===> `return *string;`

In the calling function:

`strmalloc(user_input);` ===> `strmalloc(&user_input);`

Comment: I get an error when I try to do `tmp = *realloc(*string, size);` it says `Assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void'`

Comment: @MatthewSchell typo

Comment: `*string = NULL` and `return *string` gives me a warning saying `Parameter 'string' may point to deallocated memory` do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @MatthewSchell as I see even to modify the function when all changes are given is a bit hard task for you. Here you have a complete code :https://godbolt.org/z/63odo9

Comment: Thank you so much @P__J. But I have one question. Why is the pointer to pointer needed?

Comment: to m odify its content

Comment: One last thing. in `(*string)[index++] = ch` I get a warning saying `Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined` How do I fix this?

Comment: I do not know what compiler you use. It is 100% legal in C. Use cast  `= (char)ch`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227088/discussion-between-matthew-schell-and-p-j-supports-women-in-poland).